# What is the physical meaning of the eigenvalues of a state-space representation of a physical system?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, linear-systems

Consider the following state-space model of a physical system.

$\begin{bmatrix}
\dot{{x_1}} \\
\dot{{x_2}} 
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -c/m \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\ x_1\\
\ x_2 
\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}\ 0 \\ 1/m \end{bmatrix}u
\\ y= \begin{bmatrix}\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \ x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}+[0]u$

The model represents a moving mass connected to a damper, with $x_1 = y$ (displacement), $x_2 = v$ (velocity),  $u = F$ (tractive force), $y= x_1$, $m$ being the mass and $c$ the damper coefficient. The schematic representation is given below.[image: here]

There are two eigenvalues / poles concerning this system, one if which is zero, and the other is $c/m$.

According to the solution to the ordinary differential equation represented as the state-space model, the transient behavior of this system will become slower if the mass is increased; the second eigenvalue becomes larger, hence the decrease in transient time speed, and vice-versa if the damper coefficient is increased.

I am confused at what the eigenvalue really represents here in this context. I understand that in the context of matrix transformation the eigenvalue represents the largest vector displacement magnitude, but overall I am lost as to what it exactly represents especially in the above problem.

What is it's relation to the transient behavior of the system, and why is it regarded as poles of the system? (I know that the mathematical meaning of poles is the roots to the characteristics equation of a system, but even then I don't completely get the physical meanings of poles either).

I apologize for my long list of questions. Any help regarding the above-mentioned topics is highly appreciated.

Comment: Um... There are two eigen values of what?  An eigen value is a solution to an equation that looks like so. H x = h x where H is some operator, x is a vector, and h is the eigen value. When you find the h you usually also need to find x, the eigen vector.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

Comment: I suspect you have withheld crucial information on the nature of *F(t)*. Moreover, it is a bit coy to *withhold* the explicit simple behavior of the system according to the simple differential equation $m\ddot y= -cy +F(t)$. The matrix Affine map formulation is virtually lunatic.